# ssl consumer configuration in REST delivery point

Tags: solace, solace-mq

I am creating a consumer using soladmin. consumer is an ssl consumer and the operational state is down. I am getting an error saying "local ssl Handshake failed : Server certificate verification failed : not trusted common name"

any have any ide in what situations I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the Solace appliance/VMR is not able to verify the common name of the server certificate of the REST consumer.

You can get rid of the error by either:

1. Adding the common name of the REST consumer's SSL certficate as a trusted common name for this specific REST consumer.

   a) Right click the REST consumer in SolAdmin.

   b) Left Click "Manage SSL Options"
   [image: Manage SSL Options]

   c) Add the correct trusted common name.
   [image: Add Trusted Common Name]
2. Disable "Enforce Trusted Common Name" on the VPN.

   a) Login via the CLI

   b) Enter the following series of commands, replacing `myVPN` with the actual name of your VPN.

   ```
   solace> enable
   solace# configure
   solace(configure)# message-vpn myVPN
   solace(configure/message-vpn)# rest
   solace(configure/message-vpn/rest)# ssl server-certificate-validation
   solace(...est/ssl/server-certificate-validation)# no enforce-trusted-common-name
   ```

   c) Verify that "Enforce Trusted Common Name" is now disabled. Once again, replace `myVPN` with the actual name of your VPN.

   ```
   solace> show message-vpn myVPN rest
   Message VPN:                         myVPN
   REST SSL Server Certificate Validation
         Enforce Trusted Common Name:   Disabled
         Maximum Chain Depth:           3
         Validate Certificate Dates:    Enabled
   ```